# Sefer Tefillah L'Moshe online

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, tefilin, tying-knots-kosheir

I was speaking with a sofer today and he suggested for tying tefillin knots to use a sefer entitled *Tefillah L'Moshe*. However, upon searching the title, I came across no fewer than three seperate sefarim of that title. Does anyone know of the particular version in question and if it is available on Hebrewbooks.com?

PS. I presently use *Sefer Ta'amei Haminhagim* for tying knots, so this is more about the sefer itself and the portion wherein the information is contained.

Answer (score 2):

Try:  ספר תפלה למשה והוא אוצר הלכות הנחת תפילין ולבישת הציצית חובר בס"ד ע"י משה קרויזר

Comment: There are [multiple listings](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:"משה+קרויזר") on Google Books, but no preview available. The author is mentioned [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A8#.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8_.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.99.D7.A2.D7.99).